# HTTP - What does the 'accept' header do? (In plain english)

Tags: http, header

Code I'm working with has an 'accept' header categorized as "access-control-allow-headers", but I'm not entirely sure what purpose it serves. When I take it out, it seems to work just as well. I tried deciphering its purpose on the [W3 Header Field Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) page, but it's a bit over my head. Does anyone know a simpler way to explain its function, specifically in this context?

```
var defaultCorsHeaders = {
  "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
  "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
  "access-control-allow-headers": "content-type, accept",
  "access-control-max-age": 10 // Seconds.
};
```

Comment: The "http" site you mentioned is the W3C copy of a long obsoleted IETF specification. For "Accept", have a look at <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#header.accept>. For the CORS headers, you'll need to have a look at the CORS spec (<https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/>)

Comment: Ah okay, I found the jQuery AJAX website to be a better source of 'what headers do in plain english'. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ 

@Julian Reschke Thanks for the heads up on the http site, I'll be sure to defer to other sources. Also, thanks for the CORS link!